# Who are the current members of the main Avengers team in the comics?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers

I haven't been following the Avengers comics for quite some time. I tried doing a search on Google, but all I got were conflicting or older rosters.

Who are the current members as of July 2012?

Comment: The question may be too localized in time, but I don't think it's general reference. The user spent time trying to find the answer and couldn't, which means it's not exactly easily found. I had to dig out physical issues to answer it.

Comment: @BrettWhite The question is for the "current members", which will change in the future (too localized), _and_ it [only took me ten seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_(comics)#Roster) to find (general reference). (Granted, it's not as detailed..)

Comment: I'm going to pass on the too localized question, but Brett's question is pretty significantly different from Wikipedia.  Wikipedia may contain answers to questions, but assuming it's actually right in a given case is a completely different question (no pun intended).

Comment: For the time being, I'm pretty content with Brett's response since he did state that he physically went back and looked through his collection.

The Wikia normally has what I need, but I had a couple of concerns with page. The "Current Members" at the top have characters that aren't listed anywhere in the "Current Rosters" at the bottom. And when I checked a week ago, the history showed the last accepted revision was in April 2011.

Answer (score 11):

Avengers vs. X-Men has really confused who is definitively on which team, as eveyr Avengers book currently features a squadron of some sort. Going through my back issues, though, to the issues before AvX:

**Avengers (May 2012; this is the main Avengers team, meant to have the heavy hitters in it):** Iron Man (Tony Stark), Hawkeye (Clint Barton), Spider-Woman (Jessica Drew), The Protector (Noh-Varr), Captain America (Steve Rogers), Storm (Ororo T'Challa), The Vision, The Red Hulk (Gen. Thunderbolt Ross), Quake (Daisy Johnson)

**New Avengers (June 2012; this is Luke Cage's hand-picked, street level Avengers team):** Luke Cage, Ms. Marvel (Carol Danvers), The Thing (Ben Grimm), Iron Fist (Danny Rand), Spider-Man (Peter Parker), Wolverine (James Howlett), Dr. Strange (Stephen Strange), Mockingbird (Bobbi Morse), Jessica Jones, Victoria Hand, Daredevil (Matt Murdock)

**Secret Avengers (June 2012; this is the covert ops, hidden from the public team):** Hawkeye (Clint Barton), Black Widow (Natasha Romanoff), Beast (Henry McCoy), Valkyrie (Brunnhilde), The Human Torch (Jim Hammond), Captain Britain (Brian Braddock), Venom (Flash Thompson)

**Avengers Assemble (July 2012; this title was launched in conjunction with the movie, and stars the movie's roster BUT in Marvel Comics continuity):** Captain America, Iron Man, Thor, Hulk (Bruce Banner), Black Widow, Hawkeye

Comment: What exactly is Avengers Assemble? Most of the info I found doing a quick search was about the series to replace Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes. It was mentioned on the Wikipedia page, but the link just redirected me to the movie page. I'm assuming it's just some sort of comic tie-in to the movie?

Comment: @Anthony I added a summary of what each team's purpose is

Comment: Is that the Avengers Assemble TV series, or a comic with the same name? If it's the series, then Falcon joins the Avengers on the first episode of Avengers Assemble, and remains a member throughout the series. Scott Lang Ant-Man is also a member after a while.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Avengers#Current_Rosters) the current rosters are:

> **Avengers**
>   Team Leader: Maria Hill
>
> Team Members:
>
> - Protector (Noh-Varr)
> - Hawkeye (Clint Barton)
> - Iron Man (Tony Stark)
> - Spider-Man (Peter Parker)
> - Spider-Woman (Jessica Drew)
> - Thor (Thor Odinson)
> - Wolverine (James Howlett)
> - Red Hulk (Thaddeus Ross)
>
> **"New" Avengers**
>   Team Leader: Luke Cage
>
> Team Members:
>
> - Squirrel Girl (Doreen Green)
> - Iron Fist (Daniel Rand)
> - Jewel (Jessica Jones-Cage)
> - Mockingbird (Bobbi Morse)
> - Spider-Man (Peter Parker)
> - The Thing (Ben Grimm)
> - Wolverine (James Howlett)
> - Ms. Marvel (Carol Danvers)
> - Victoria Hand
>
> **"Secret" Avengers**
>
> Team Leader: Steve Rogers
>
> Team Members:
>
> - Ant-Man (Eric O'Grady)
> - Beast (Henry McCoy)
> - Black Widow (Natasha Romanoff)
> - Moon Knight (Marc Spector)
> - Nova (Richard Rider)
> - Sharon Carter
> - Valkyrie (Brunnhilde)
> - War Machine (James Rhodes)

More on Marvel.com: http://marvel.com/universe/Avengers#ixzz1zAbjQkWf

Comment: Those are actually a few months old. I know that Storm and Black panther are on the Avengers, and Hawkeye and Captain Britain are on Secret Avengers (and Moon Knight, Nova and War Machine are not). Avengers vs. X-Men has confused everything.